# How can I prompt a unique file download in html?

Tags: java, html

I'm writing a program that allows users to sign up to a website. After they sign up, I want to create a copy of a generic image, change the name of the image so it matches the username, and prompt a file download. I'm a bit confused as to how I can implement this in HTML. I have the code to create a copy of the image and change the name, but I'm not sure how to connect this to my HTML code to get the user input.

I just uploaded some of my code (please don't judge I'm a beginner). Basically, I want to create a database in which the interns of the company get their own badge based on their role. After they register on the database, I want there to be a prompt that tells them to download their unique png file.

```java
package org.kodejava.example.commons.io;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileCopyExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File consumer = new File("consumer.png");
        File sweIntern = new File("sweIntern.png");
        File HRTeamLeader = new File("HRTeamLeader.png");
        File HRTeamMember = new File("HRTeamMember.png");
        File onlineMarketingStrategist = new File("onlineMarketingStrategist.png");
        File marketingTeamMember = new File("marketingTeamMember.png");
        File medicalResearchTeamLeader = new File("medicalResearchTeamLeader.png");
        File medicalResearchTeamMember = new File("medicalResearchTeamMember.png"); 
        
        //somehow get username and role from dropdown menu
        File target = ("username.png");
        File targetDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));

        try {
            if(role == "Consumer"){
                 FileUtils.copy(consumer, target);
                 FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(consumer, targetDir);
                 //repeat for 8 other roles
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
        <label for="roles">Select your role:</label>
            <select name="roles" id="roles">
            <option value="Consumer">Consumer</option>
            <option value="Software Engineer Intern">Software Engineer Intern</option>
            <option value="HR Team Leader">HR Team Leader</option>
            <option value="HR Team Member">HR Team Member</option>  
            <option value="Online Marketing Strategist">Online Marketing Strategist</option>
            <option value="Online Marketing Team Member">Online Marketing Team Member</option>
            <option value="Medical Research Team Leader">Medical Research Team Leader</option>
            <option value="Medical Research Innovation Leader">Medical Research Innovation Leader</option>
            <option value="Biomedical Research Team Member">HR Team Leader</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Show us what you got so far so we can help you. We're flying blind here right now

Comment: I added some of my code

Comment: What does the Java code have to do with the HTML. The Java code doesn't seem to be part of a web application. General hint for beginners: Don't get fancy. If you want the user to download something just give them a regular link (`<a href="image.png">Download</a>`)